# Deploying a shared folder shortcut based on individual user accounts - Windows 2008 Domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-domain, file-server

Is it possible to create a shortcut that references a shared folder on a file server for specific individuals on a windows 2008 domain?

I know you can do it with group policies, but I don't want to create an OU for each individual user.

Detailed example..

I have a file server that has shared folder for 3 different users.
User one: Mike
User two: Tom
user three: Jim

Shared folders:
\fileserver\Jim_Shared\
\fileserver\Tom_Shared\
\fileserver\Mike_Shared\

I know I can manually create the shortcuts, but is there an easier way to configure this to automatically happen under there domain account? This way say Jim  uses Tom's computer, whenever he signs in he will see the shortcut to his personal folder instead of Tom's?

Comment: Why not use GGP with Item Level Targeting and the %username% variable to map a drive letter to a shared folder that matches the username?

Comment: Didn't think of that. It is only maybe 5 out of 90 users that have a shared folder, do you think this would be efficient?

Comment: Efficient in what way?

Comment: Does item targeting allow you to specify specific AD users to apply the policy to vs OUs to apply the policy to?

Comment: Do you want to answer the question, i used your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use Group Policy Preferences with Item Level Targeting and the %username% variable to map a drive letter to a shared folder that matches the username.